# locationManager:didUpdateToLocation not called

Tags: ios, maps, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I need some help.

When I open Maps I have to grep my current location and send it to server to get all other pins from it. (Like what is nearby ).

I set :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // if location services are on
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        // if location services are restricted do nothing
        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
            [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
        {
            NSLog(@"Location tracking disabled.");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"all ok");
            self.locationMeneger = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            self.locationMeneger.delegate = self;
            [self.locationMeneger setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
            [self.locationMeneger setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
            [self.locationMeneger startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

My log print our "all ok" so location meneger is initalized, but none of delegate

```
// for iOS 6 and more
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    NSLog(@"je updatan");
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(NearByPinOnMap) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
 // for iOS 5 and lass
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(NSArray *)locations fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"nov update");
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(NearByPinOnMap) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error maps : %@", error.description);
}
```

is almost never called. There ware few times that this didUpdateToLocation was called but without changes next time didn't.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set desiredAccuracy parameter. You can read about it here:[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy).
You might also check if your class adopts CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol

Comment: Hi, I try that and I see that if I wait long enough it call delegate more often. Is there any other way to get current location more quick?